# How to recover the ZFS filesystem and the associated mountpoints and the data

Tags: 16.04

I am facing an issue with my current Ubuntu system.

Its with one SSD disk with operating system and three additional disk which are associated with zpool array.

One fine day morning the SSd disk which contains Ubuntu OS is not detecting by the system BIOs and stopped to boot the machine.

The only option pending was to replace the SSD disk with a new one. Due to the delay for getting the SSD hardisk, I was decided to install a normal SATA (500gb) and installed the Ubuntu 16 LTS time being and try to access the ZFS mount points to recover the data in it.

Unfortunately am not able to access the ZFS volume and the associated mount points. Currently am looking for your help to retrieve the data.

I am attaching the current output of the "zpool status -x"command.

```
root@phoenix-H97M-HD3:~# zpool status -x
  pool: datastore
 state: UNAVAIL
status: The pool has been upgraded to a newer, incompatible on-disk version.
    The pool cannot be accessed on this system.
action: Access the pool from a system running more recent software, or
    restore the pool from backup.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-A5
 scrub: none requested
config:

NAME                                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
datastore                                             UNAVAIL      0     0     0  newer version
  raidz1-0                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
    disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W500PE48-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
    disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W500PC79-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
    disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W500Q2GG-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

`zpool import` is not giving any output.while executing this com it simply goes to the next line of the command prompt.

Comment: Have you tried to run `zpool import` ? That should scan your disks, and report which pools are available for import. Then `zpool import <poolname>` to actually import (make available) that poolname.

Comment: Hi Soren,  I am not able to do it. As I mentioned above the pool sgows " UNAVAIL" and the "raidz1 and disk shows "online".

Comment: While I execute the "zpool status -xv"

Comment: Can you advice me what is the real procedure to recover in these scenarios....

Comment: I can't share the screenshot of my screen, since I dont have required reputation to upload the image...

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of `zpool status -x` and `zpool import` commands ? Just cut&paste it into the question  as text.

Comment: please find the below out put in two "commnent: fiewl.

Comment: root@phoenix-H97M-HD3:~# zpool status -x
  pool: datastore
 state: UNAVAIL
status: The pool has been upgraded to a newer, incompatible on-disk version.
 The pool cannot be accessed on this system.
action: Access the pool from a system running more recent software, or
 restore the pool from backup.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-A5

Comment: config:

 NAME                                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
 datastore                                             UNAVAIL      0     0     0  newer version
   raidz1-0                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
     disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W500PE48-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
     disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W500PC79-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
     disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1ER166_W500Q2GG-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0